# Send email with attachment in Codeigniter but with PHP`s mail function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, email, twitter-bootstrap

I`m using simple php mail() function for sending emails in Codeigniter 2.1.2. with Bootstrap 2.3.2. and jQuery validation.It works great for me but now I need to add "attachment" field.I know that Codeigniter have its own email class/helper but I do not want to start from a scratch with it,since I am a newbie and I want to keep existing code with necessary changes if possible.I reasearched a bit but have not found similar solution,also I am aware that it might be trickier than I think.How do I change my controller to solve this problem?

Here is HTML part:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal-contact-form">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" name="sentMessage" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" >
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name"/>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email"/>

                </div>

            <label for="userfile" class="control-label">Your file (max.20mb):</label>

            <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" />

            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="message" class="control-label">Message:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="10" rows="5"
                    required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message"
                    minlength="5" data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <div id="success"> </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a id="close" href="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
public function contact()
{    

    if(empty($_POST['name'])                  ||
    empty($_POST['email'])                 ||
    empty($_POST['message'])        ||
    !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo "No arguments Provided!";
        return false;
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = 'email@myemail.com';
    $email_subject = "Contact: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
                              " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ".
                              "Email: $email_address\n Message: \n $message";
    $headers = "From: email@myemail.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";        
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    return true;   
}
}
```

and Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation

```
$(function() { $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
{
 preventSubmit: true,
 submitError: function($form, event, errors) {

 },
 submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault();

   var name = $("input#name").val();  
   var email = $("input#email").val(); 
   var message = $("textarea#message").val();
   var firstName = name; 
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
       firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
     }        
     $.ajax({
            url: "http://somesite.com/main/contact",
                type: "POST",
                data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
                cache: false,
                success: function() {  
                   $('#close').text("Close");
                   $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                   $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append( "</button>");
                  $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
               $('#success > .alert-success')
                     .append('</div>');

               //clear all fields
               $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
           },
                error: function() {                
                // Fail message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                 .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong>");
             $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
             //clear all fields
             $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
         },
       })
     },
     filter: function() {
               return $(this).is(":visible");
     },
   });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab("show");});});$('#name').focus(function() {$('#success').html('');});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Answer (score 0):

You can make a common function to send email using `PHP mail() function` just like below.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
```

where you can pass the parameter i.e.

```
$my_file = "somefile.zip";
$my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_path_here/";
$my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
$my_mail = "my@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```

But I recommended to use `CI Email Library` because it helps you to send larger attachment and it's easy to debug the mail error in it.